# How do i use the ecm package in r and what does xtr and xeq represent?

Tags: r

I have 2variables inflation and exchange rates.i want to k ow the the long run relationship between the variables using ecm in however i cannot firgure out what is xtr and xeq in the codes. Please help

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ecm/versions/4.4.0/topics/ecm

Comment: Yes i have. But my data has two variables and i can't firgure out how to do it, like should my xeq be in terms of ln or?